# New soldier joins isolated base experimenting on dead Vietnam soldiers

Tags: identify-this-movie

I believe this movie is about 10 years old and has a US military base whose commander is conducting some form of medical experiments on soldiers believed dead or missing in action during the Vietnam era. A new soldier assigned here finds the hidden men and befriends one of them. When he questions the others stationed here, he is believed to be making it up or crazy because of the station's solitude. The solitude helps isolate the experiment from discovery.

The mention of the Vietnam era experimentation will conjure ideas of Jacob's Ladder. It is not. This movie was not horror.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is [Guy X](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0408828/) starring Jason Biggs of American Pie fame. The description on IMDB isn't great the [wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_X) has a slightly better one. He is accidentally stationed at nowhere base that has secret Vietnam war soldiers being kept at it. It's a black comedy similar in tone to Catch-22.

Comment: I recognize the Tagline: There's Been a F**kup, Sir! Also, the mistaken identity angle. And when I read a few reviews, I remember also, the ending wasn't very satisfying. Like they didn't know what movie they were making. Thanks.

Comment: @wbogacz Yeah the ending really seemed like it wasn't sure it was supposed to be there. It just didn't tie anything together and left every plot device behind like it was trying to make a new movie in the last 5 minutes.